# Frequency Analysis (DFT / FFT) of a Signal Without a Constant Sampling Frequency (Non Uniform Sampling in Time Domain)

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, dft, frequency, fourier

I'm a stack exchange user for some time and now I'm registering to ask a simple question (I think!).

I have a vibration signal with an amplitude and time (sampling frequency not constant) in  a $10000\times 2$ double variable.

The data is available at: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoCOij4si31tzgY89bhr6XH-_gQq

How can I do some sort of frequency analysis (FFT, DFT) or similar. How can I do it in Matlab?

Sorry if the question is duplicated but I couldn't find any answer for my problem.

Comment: Did you find this: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16590/non-uniform-fft-with-fftw

Comment: Taking the FFT of the data without using the time index shows at least one strong frequency.  Do you need to use the time index? See [this plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5e23.png).

Comment: I added a long analysis on how to derive the Uniform DFT of Non Uniformly Sampled Time Series. @PeterK., I think you'd like it.

Comment: @Royi Cool! Thank-you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The DFT Matrix for Non Uniform Time Samples Series

### Problem Statement

We have a signal $ x \left( t \right) $ defined on the interval $ \left[ {T}_{1}, {T}_{2} \right] $.
Assume we have $ N $ samples of it given by $ \left\{ x \left( {t}_{i} \right) \right\}_{i = 0}^{N - 1} $. The samples time $ {t}_{i} $ is arbitrary and not necessarily uniform.

We're after the DFT of the samples $ \left\{ X \left[ k \right] \right\}_{k = 0}^{K - 1} $ as it was samples in a uniform manner (Implicitly means the samples in Frequency domain will be uniform as well).

### Deriving the Connection

In the [DFT Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) the connection between time and frequency is given by:

$$ x \left[ n \right] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k = 0}^{N - 1} X \left[ k \right] {e}^{j 2 \pi \frac{k}{N} n } \tag{1} \label{EqnIdft} $$

In $ \eqref{EqnIdft} $ we use $ n $ for modeling the sample index in time. We usually build samples in time as $ x \left[ n \right] = x \left( n {T}_{s} \right) $ where $ {T}_{s} $ is a uniform sampling interval.
Hence we could write:

$$ x \left( n {T}_{s} \right) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k = 0}^{N - 1} X \left[ k \right] {e}^{j 2 \pi \frac{k}{N {T}_{s}} n {T}_{s}} \tag{2} \label{EqnIdft2} $$

In $ \eqref{EqnIdft2} $ we added explicit scaling of time. This is a known property of Fourier transform family which scales the domain in order to normalize the transform.

Now, there is nothing which blocks us from using arbitrary time:

$$\begin{align*} \tag{3} \label{EqnIdft3}
x \left( t \right) & = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k = 0}^{N - 1} X \left[ k \right] {e}^{j 2 \pi \frac{k}{N {T}_{s}} t} && \text{} \\ 
& = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k = 0}^{N - 1} X \left[ k \right] {e}^{j 2 \pi \frac{k {F}_{s}}{N} t} && \text{Since $ {F}_{s} = \frac{1}{{T}_{s}} $}
\end{align*}$$

As can be seen $ \eqref{EqnIdft3} $ makes sense as it goes through each element according to its frequency and sums to give the output at time $ t $. We can go step farther and generalize it for cases we don't have uniform sampling frequency.
The average sampling frequency is given by $ \bar{F}_{s} = \frac{N}{ {T}_{2} - {T}_{1} } $. Let's define $ T = {T}_{2} - {T}_{1} $ and we'll get:

$$ x \left( t \right) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k = 0}^{N - 1} X \left[ k \right] {e}^{ j 2 \pi k \frac{t}{T} } $$

Which is many ways resembles the [DTFT Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) equation which does the same in the other direction, transforming uniform discrete samples in time domain to arbitrary frequency (Within a frequency interval) in Frequency Domain:

$$\begin{align*} \tag{4}
X \left( f \right) & = \sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1} x \left[ n \right] {e}^{-j 2 \pi f {T}_{s} n } && \text{} \\
& = \sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1} x \left[ n \right] {e}^{-j 2 \pi \frac{f}{ {F}_{s} } n } && \text{Since $ {F}_{s} = \frac{1}{{T}_{s}} $}
\end{align*}$$

We see the same scaling, $ \frac{f}{ {F}_{s} } $ which scales the continuous $ f $ relative to the interval of frequencies $ {F}_{s} $ which is equivalent to $ \frac{t}{ T } $ which scales $ t $ relative to the time interval of the continuous signal.

### The Transform Matrix

So, given the set of time indices $ {\left\{ {t}_{i} \right\}}_{i = 0}^{N - 1} $ the transformation matrix, from frequency domain to time domain, is given by:

$$ D \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}, \;  {D}_{i, k} = {e}^{ j 2 \pi k \frac{ {t}_{i} }{T} } $$

### The Model

In vector form the model is:

$$ x = D y $$

Where $ y \in \mathbb{C}^{K} $ is the vector of the frequency coefficients in uniform grid, $ x $ is the samples in time (Non Uniform, Or at least no assumption of uniformity) and $ D $ as defined above.
Since in our model we're after $ y $ the answer is given by:

$$ y = {D}^{\dagger} x $$

Where $ {D}^{\dagger} $ is the [Pseudo Inverse Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $ D $.

### Implementation & Results

The code is as following:

```
subStreamNumberDefault = 79;

run('InitScript.m');

figureIdx           = 0;
figureCounterSpec   = '%04d';

generateFigures = ON;


%% Simulation Parameters

samplingFrequency = 101; %<! [Hz]
samplingInterval = 1 / samplingFrequency; %<! [Sec]
startTime = 1; %<! [Sec]
endTime = 4; %<! [Sec]
timeInterval = endTime - startTime; %<! [Sec]

numSamples = round(samplingFrequency * timeInterval);
numSamplesTT = round(1.2 * numSamples);

signalFreq = 2; %!< [Hz]

% The uniform time grid
vT      = linspace(startTime, endTime, numSamples + 1);
vT(end) = [];
vT      = vT(:);

% The non uniform time grid - Reconstruction
vTT = endTime * rand(numSamplesTT, 1);
vTT = sort(vTT, 'ascend');

% The non uniform time grid - DFT
vTD = linspace(startTime, endTime, (10 * numSamples) + 1);
vTD(end) = [];
vTD = vTD(sort(randperm(length(vTD), numSamples)));
vTD = vTD(:);

% The uniform frequency grid
vF      = (samplingFrequency / 2) * linspace(-1, 1, numSamples + 1);
vF(end) = [];
vF      = vF(:);

vK = [-floor(numSamples / 2):floor((numSamples - 1) / 2)];
vK = vK(:);


%% Generate Data

vX  = cos(2 * pi * signalFreq * vT);
vFx = fftshift(fft(vX));


figureIdx = figureIdx + 1;

hFigure         = figure('Position', figPosLarge);
hAxes           = subplot(1, 2, 1);
hLineSeries     = plot(vT, vX);
set(hLineSeries, 'LineWidth', lineWidthNormal);
set(get(hAxes, 'Title'), 'String', {['Reference Signal']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
set(get(hAxes, 'XLabel'), 'String', {['Time Index']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
set(get(hAxes, 'YLabel'), 'String', {['Sample Value']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);

hAxes           = subplot(1, 2, 2);
hStemObj = stem(vF, abs(vFx));
set(hStemObj, 'LineWidth', lineWidthNormal);
set(get(hAxes, 'Title'), 'String', {['DFT of the Reference Signal']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
set(get(hAxes, 'XLabel'), 'String', {['Frequency [Hz]']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
set(get(hAxes, 'YLabel'), 'String', {['Magnitude']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);

if(generateFigures == ON)
    saveas(hFigure,['Figure', num2str(figureIdx, figureCounterSpec), '.png']);
end


%% Analysis - Reconstruction

mD = exp(1j * 2 * pi * (vTT / timeInterval) * vK.') / numSamples;

% Reconstruction according to the model
vY = real(mD * vFx);

figureIdx = figureIdx + 1;

hFigure         = figure('Position', figPosLarge);
hAxes           = axes();
set(hAxes, 'NextPlot', 'add');
hLineSeries     = plot(vT, vX);
set(hLineSeries, 'LineWidth', lineWidthNormal);
hLineSeries     = plot(vTT, vY);
set(hLineSeries, 'LineWidth', lineWidthNormal, 'LineStyle', ':', 'Marker', '*');
set(get(hAxes, 'Title'), 'String', {['Uniform Signal & Non Uniform Signal']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
set(get(hAxes, 'XLabel'), 'String', {['Time Index']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
set(get(hAxes, 'YLabel'), 'String', {['Sample Value']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
hLegend = ClickableLegend({['Uniform Signal'], ['Non Uniform Signal']});

if(generateFigures == ON)
    saveas(hFigure,['Figure', num2str(figureIdx, figureCounterSpec), '.png']);
end


%% Analysis - DFT of the Non Uniformly Sampled Data

vY  = cos(2 * pi * signalFreq * vTD);

mD = exp(1j * 2 * pi * (vTD / timeInterval) * vK.') / numSamples;
vFy = pinv(mD) * vY;

figureIdx = figureIdx + 1;

hFigure         = figure('Position', figPosLarge);
hAxes           = axes();
set(hAxes, 'NextPlot', 'add');
hLineSeries     = plot(vT, vX);
set(hLineSeries, 'LineWidth', lineWidthNormal);
hLineSeries     = plot(vTD, vY);
set(hLineSeries, 'LineWidth', lineWidthNormal, 'LineStyle', ':', 'Marker', '*');
set(get(hAxes, 'Title'), 'String', {['Uniform Signal & Non Uniform Signal']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
set(get(hAxes, 'XLabel'), 'String', {['Time Index']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
set(get(hAxes, 'YLabel'), 'String', {['Sample Value']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
hLegend = ClickableLegend({['Uniform Signal'], ['Non Uniform Signal']});

if(generateFigures == ON)
    saveas(hFigure,['Figure', num2str(figureIdx, figureCounterSpec), '.png']);
end

figureIdx = figureIdx + 1;

hFigure     = figure('Position', figPosLarge);
hAxes       = axes();
set(hAxes, 'NextPlot', 'add');
hStemObj    = stem(vF, abs([vFx, vFy]));
set(hStemObj, 'LineWidth', lineWidthNormal);
% hLineSeries     = plot(vTT, vY);
% set(hLineSeries, 'LineWidth', lineWidthNormal, 'LineStyle', ':', 'Marker', '*');
set(get(hAxes, 'Title'), 'String', {['DFT of the Uniform Signal & Non Uniform Signal']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
set(get(hAxes, 'XLabel'), 'String', {['Frequency [Hz]']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
set(get(hAxes, 'YLabel'), 'String', {['Magnitude']}, ...
    'FontSize', fontSizeTitle);
hLegend = ClickableLegend({['Uniform Signal'], ['Non Uniform Signal']});

if(generateFigures == ON)
    saveas(hFigure,['Figure', num2str(figureIdx, figureCounterSpec), '.png']);
end
```

Results are:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### Summary

In this post we derived how to estimate the Uniform DFT of a Non Uniform Time Series by solving linear system of equations.

The full code is available on my [StackExchange Signal Processing Q32137 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q32137` folder).

### Remark: Why Do We Need to Apply `fftshift()` on the DFT of the Signal?

Indeed in the Reconstruction part we use `fftshift()`. The shallow answer is easy, we also build the vector `vK` as symmetric around zero.
But there is a deeper reason for that. In the DFT when we use uniform sampling in Frequency Domain and Time Domain *Magic* happens without us seeing it explicitly.

When we defined the term $ \frac{k}{ N {T}_{s} } n {T}_{s} $ we replaces $ n {T}_{s} $ with $ t $ hence we prevent the term $ {T}_{s} $ to cancel itself. Now setting $ {F}_{s} = \frac{1}{{T}_{s}} $ means that we multiply by $ k $ and we get frequencies which are out of the Nyquist Frequency.
In most cases when we that happens the Modulo property of the exponent comes in and we get the correct negative value of the frequency in the range $ \left[ -\pi, \pi \right] $. Yet when $ t $ is arbitrary we can think that $ {F}_{s} $ is changing per sample which means when we go farther than $ \pi $ the modulo doesn't bring us to the correct answer.

First, as intuition, always think the DFT is defined on the $ \left[ -\pi, \pi \right] $ interval and it is continuous. So as long as you work on this range things works as intended. This intuition can come from the Fourier Series and Discrete Fourier Series (DFS).

Let's try explaining it using a concrete example. Let's examine the exponent term from the derivation:

$$ 2 \pi \frac{k}{N {T}_{s}} n {T}_{S} = 2 \pi \frac{k}{{F}_{S}} \frac{{F}_{s}}{N} n = 2 \pi \frac{k b}{{F}_{s}} n $$

Where $ b $ is the Bin Resolution in the Frequency domain. Now given the signal is:

$$ x \left( t \right) = \cos \left( 2 \pi f t \right) \Rightarrow x \left( n {T}_{s} \right) = \cos \left( 2 \pi f {T}_{s} n \right) \Rightarrow x \left[ n \right] = \cos \left( 2 \pi \frac{f}{ {F}_{s} } n \right) $$

For $ {F}_{s} = 100 $ [Hz] and $ N = 100 $ (Which means $ b = 1 $) we will have delta at $ k = 2 $ and $ k = 98 $. For $ k = 98 $:

$$ 2 \pi \frac{98}{{F}_{s}} n $$

This is clearly above the Nyquist frequency ($ \frac{{F}_{s}}{2} $) and only for $ {F}_{s} = 100 $ its modulo is $ -2 $ which is correct. But in the model above, since we have arbitrary $ t $ one could think we have changing $ {F}_{s} $ which means we don't get the correct value.

This means the actual equation should be:

$$ x \left( t \right) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k = \left \lfloor - \frac{K}{2} \right \rfloor }^{ \left \lfloor \frac{K - 1}{2} \right \rfloor } X \left[ k \right] {e}^{ j 2 \pi k \frac{t}{T} } $$

Comment: What's the acuracy of this conversion from nonuniform to uniform samples? Any constraints on the distribution of $t_i$ ?

Comment: I derived it today. Since it is my own thinking I have nothing to based my thoughts upon. The accuracy will depend on how close the Matrix to singular. The close it will the less accurate the solution. Guess which matrix has the best conditional number? This with equispaced sampling :-). I don't think there is specific constraint on the distribution. Just the insight I wrote, the better conditioned `mD` the closer you get to the ground truth. As far as I can see, it is at least good as the state of the art in literature.

Comment: Hmm what's the state of the art in the literature? And do you know what is its reconstruction accuracy  in dBs?

Comment: @Fat32, I guess algorithms like NUDFT. Regarding your question, well it really depends on the matrix `mD`. I would say it will always be good enough for analysis of signals (Dominant frequency and all other stuff we do in frequency). I think the case I gave above is one of the hardest. Sampling grid is all random. I'd say in most real world cases where it is close to uniform with some missing values it will be almost perfect.

Comment: By the way, in order to mitigate noise amplification in case `mD` is not well conditioned one could easily use [Tikhonov Regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization).

Comment: hmm thanks for the link...

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, and even nonuniform time sampling can be beneficial to processing in some cases.

First, have a look at the data: the sampling intervals are shown here:
[image: sampling intervals]

Quite regular (around 2000 in average), with fluctuation around this value,  similar to jitter, except at some  locations where you have a huge variations. You should carefully check those, and filter them if you suspect they are not normal. I have more concerns about your signal:

[image: amplitude]

A lot of zeroes, only positive values. Looks like you have absolute values. Traditional vibration signals do not look like that.

Anyway, you can invest in [non-uniform DFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16590/non-uniform-fft-with-fftw), as proposed by @Jojek.

You can have a look at the [Lomb-Scargle periodogram or least-squares frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares_spectral_analysis),

> a classic method for finding periodicity in irregularly-sampled data

On your data, you get this, but I would not dare interpret, given the warning above:
[image: Lomb-Scargle]

Recent matlab versions are for instance [`plomb.m`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/plomb.html), and fast ones exist in [Python](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2015/06/13/lomb-scargle-in-python/). MatlabCentral offers at least three implementations:

- [Lomb (Lomb-Scargle) Periodogram](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20004-lomb--lomb-scargle--periodogram)
- [lombscargle.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/993-lombscargle-m)
- [Lomb normalized periodogram](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22215-lomb-normalized-periodogram)

Comment: Understood

Thank you all for the help! The signal was from an analog piezo sensor which reads only positive values!