# Compensation for Irregular Time Step for DFT (FFT)

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, sampling, nyquist, time-frequency

I want to run a clustering algorithm (svm, knn) on the ferquency spectrum data of a temperature sensor that published at irregular times. 
Here is the temperature data to take the FFT:

[image]
I got the mean frequency for this temperature data as well as every temp sensor in the dataframe the average is every 18mins, longest distance between 2 points is 3hrs:

```
# group by short id
groups = df.groupby('id')
time_diff = groups.apply(lambda df: df.published_at.diff().mean())
```

Isolated the graphed temp data in a series:

```
signal = df.loc[df['_id'] == 'A1']['temperature']
```

Stored size of signal and mean sampling frequency as variables:

```
# sampling frequency: 
Fs = time_diff[:1]
Fs
Out[217]: 00:18:54.085526

# size 
S = signal.size
Then took the fft and calculated dBs

X = np.fft.fft(signal)
X_db = 20*np.log10(2*np.abs(X)/S)
And plotted the results:

plt.plot(X)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.plot(X_db)
plt.show()
```

[image]

These graphs intuitively do not look like they correspond to the original data. The objective with the fft is to then classify the data using SVM, however, I am not sure which variant fft is appropriate, nor if using the mean time frequency is either.

Comment: Just an [idea](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16590/non-uniform-fft-with-fftw).

Comment: @jojek, I added analysis in the question [Frequency Analysis of a Signal Without a Constant Sampling Frequency (Non Uniform Sampling in Time Domain)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/32137). What do you think?

Comment: @Evan, I think you can go to my answer in the other question (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/61164/128) and just run it on your data and get uniform DFT.

Answer (score 2):

One option, in addition to the Non-uniform DFT that has been mentioned, is simply interpolating the data on a regularly-spaced grid by using a timestep approximately the same size as the smallest timestep, and then taking the DFT on the interpolated data.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the non uniform DFT

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform

Google (nonuniform fft) and many useful references will be returned

and also

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/593/how-do-i-take-the-fft-of-unevenly-spaced-data